# How to fetch data paged with AMP

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to fetch data using amp list and I wanna make it paged so I have followed those steps
[Paged amp-list](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/interactivity-dynamic-content/paged_list/)
and as you see is a horrible explaining I'm trying to do the same but I didn't get the same result
I have built a backend who give me data by page
`http://localhost:3200/api/post?page=1` 
and for AMP

```
<amp-list width="auto" height="2000" layout="fixed-height" src="http://localhost:3200/api/post" [src]="'http://localhost:3200/api/post?page=' + pageNumber" binding="no" reset-on-refresh>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
         {{#posts}}
         <article class="has-post-thumbnail">
                <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
                <p>{{content}}</p>
         </article>
        {{/posts}}
     </template>
</amp-list>
<div class="navigation">
     <button class="prev" hidden [hidden]="pageNumber < 2" on="tap: AMP.setState({ pageNumber: 1 })">
              Previous
     </button>
     <button class="next" [hidden]="page ? pageNumber >= page.items.pageCount : false" on="tap: AMP.setState({ pageNumber: 2 })">
              Next
     </button>
</div>
<amp-state id="page" src="http://localhost:3200/api/post" [src]="'http://localhost:3200/api/post?page=' + pageNumber">
</amp-state>
```

when I click on buttons nothing change

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just [src] of amp accept only request with https